# Is it possible to upgrade Oracle Linux 7 to 8 in place?

Tags: linux, upgrade, operating-system, oracle-linux

I noticed in the Oracle Linux 7 documentation, there's a procedure for upgrading the operating system in place for OL6 -> OL7, but I can't seem to find the same instructions for OL7 -> OL8. Is it possible to upgrade in this way?

[Oracle Instructions for OL6 -> OL7](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/7/install/ol7-upgrade-inplace.html)

Comment: I was looking for it as well and currently isn't possible..
https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/8/relnotes8.2/ol8-issues-known.html#ol-issues-noupgrade